# Issue running rails server after Mac OS X 10.9.2 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I recently upgrade to Mavericks (10.9.2). Now, when I try to run my sample app that was working fine in the older version 10.8.x, I am getting the following error. I get a similar error when I try to run `bundle install`. Any idea what is going on here?

```
sample_app jim$ rails server
/Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/sha1.bundle
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/rails_projects/Sample_App/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'



group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1' # thoughtbot
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2' #updated to .0.2
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'sunspot_rails'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on' , '~> 2.4.1' #gem for tagging
#gem 'protected_attributes' #protected attributes

gem 'thread_safe', '0.2.0' #added to fix error

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

UPDATE:

Ran RVM commands as prescribed.  After running `rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0` I got the following errors:

```
Error running 'env GEM_HOME= GEM_PATH= /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby -d /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/setup.rb',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/jim/.rvm/log/1397496177_ruby-2.0.0-p451/rubygems.install.log
  Reason: image not found - /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/psych.bundle
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems.rb:616:in `load_yaml'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in `load_file'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/jim/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You might have to `rvm implode` and start over as it looks like a lot of the dynamic libraries you're linked against are missing or invalid.

Comment: I just said how: `rvm implode` and reinstall RVM, etc.

Comment: I upgraded to Mavericks 10.9.2 just last week (7 April). I did an `rvm implode` and reinstall defensively (i.e. before even trying to run any project work). I also use Homebrew and found that the brew linking scheme had got horribly confused (it would claim everything was installed, but not make libraries available to link when building or running gems). If you are using `brew`, then as well as re-installing `rvm` from scratch I suggest removing then re-installing brew and any libraries/utils you have with it. Took me a whole day . . .